# Htaccess: Can't rewrite an URL

Tags: .htaccess

Premise: I hate htaccess

I have to redirect or rewrite an URL: I want that this URL

```
http://www.example.com/en.php
```

become

```
http://www.example.com/en/
```

For example: clicking a link like `<a href="en">English</a>` I want that it navigates to the page `en.php` but showing the url `http://www.example.com/en/`

I've tried this, but doesn't work

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/en/ http://www.example.com/en.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: First of all, have you enable mod_rewrite on your server? And allow overwrite in your virtualhost configuration?

Comment: If all configuration set, please check this post about how to omit .php in your url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess

Comment: The leading / gets stripped off the URI to match, and the trailing / can be made optional:  `^en/?$`

Answer (score 0):

This solved:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase / 
  RewriteRule ^en en.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^en/$ en.php
```